# Apache2.4 won't start when adding php load_module in httpd.conf

Tags: apache2

I am trying to configure php 5.4.9 with apache 2.4 but when i include the lines below apache won't start.

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

I've checked all my file paths and they are all ok. I have the path set in environment to `C:\php;c:\Apache24;c:\Apache24\bin;`.

The error I'm actually getting is

```
Windows could not start the Apache2.4 on local computer. For more information, review the system eventlog. If this is a non-microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1
```

Anybody else ever have this issue?

UPDATE

I do have `php5apache2_4.dll` in the php folder and my error logs in apache

```
[Sun Dec 09 11:19:16.502272 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5552:tid 316] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5052    
[Sun Dec 09 11:19:18.315156 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5052:tid 208] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.    
[Sun Dec 09 11:29:53.861913 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5552:tid 316] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.    
[Sun Dec 09 11:29:55.889916 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5052:tid 208] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.    
[Sun Dec 09 11:29:55.905516 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5552:tid 316] AH00430: Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

Comment: Are you sure the `c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll` is existing?

Comment: You can take a look at the apache error log as mentioned in the error. What does the error log say?

Comment: Yes the php5apache2_4.dll is in the php folder, this is what is in the error logs

[Sun Dec 09 11:29:53.861913 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5552:tid 316] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Dec 09 11:29:55.889916 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5052:tid 208] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Dec 09 11:29:55.905516 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5552:tid 316] AH00430: Parent: Child process exited successfully.

Comment: updated question with errors

Comment: I am having the same problem with PHP 5.4.16. Checking the Windows error log, I get this message: `Cannot load D:/php/php-5.4.16/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The Apache service named is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: And I just found out that it was caused by the fact that I had a 64-bit Apache with a 32-bit PHP. More info here: [link](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4696)